# Rails: form_for checkbox set to true or false whether the box is checked/unchecked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a model called users that has 2 boolean attributes `send_email` and `send_text`. I have a form that edits the User model, and I want it to set those attributes to true/false depending on whether the box is check/unchecked. Here is my form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %> <br />
        <%= f.text_area :email %> <br />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :cell %> <br />
        <%= f.text_area :cell %> <br />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Get Email" %> <br />
        <%= f.check_box :send_email, {}, true, false %> <br />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Get Text" %> <br />
        <%= f.check_box :send_text, {}, true, false %> <br />
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "button small radius" %>
  <%= link_to "go back", @user, class: "button small radius secondary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the `update` action of the `user_controller`

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to @user
end
```

The form and update looks like it works perfectly, but when i submit this form with the send_email or send_text box checked, it does not change the attributes of the user model (send_email,send_text) to false

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: it does not work lol. sorry i forgot to post that, the form and update works perfectly, but when i submit this form with the send_email or send_text box checked, it does not change the attributes of the user model (send_email,send_text) to false

Comment: I noticed a strange behaviour where if `User` model has a validation defined for presence for example,

    validates :send_email, :send_text, presence: true

then the Active model will raise a validation error when form_for assigns :send_email, :send_text value of `"0"` or `"false"` if these values are used as it is. If the validation is remove then (strings) `"0"` or `"false"` works like  `false`(FalseClass)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Rails will do this for you when your form is acting on an object, just leave all the extra stuff off the tag like so:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Get Email" %> <br />
    <%= f.check_box :send_email %> <br />
</div>
```

And it should all start working as you expect. The checkboxes will be ticked if the attribute is true, and vice versa the checked state when you submit the form will affect the attribute. Rest of your code is fine.

Answer (score 3):

*Further informations about forms and updating database*

Indeed, the last answer is right : using the form_for syntax is enough and Rails will do the association unchecked:false / checked:true for you.

> ```
> <div class="field">
>     <%= f.label "Get Email" %> <br />
>     <%= f.check_box :send_email %> <br />
> </div>
> ```

I had the same problem even with that syntax. The fact is the server's console returned me `Unpermitted parameter: checkbox_value` : don't forget to update your required/permitted parameters to put into `params` ! And in my case :

```
# ***_controller.rb
      private
        def operator_params
          params.require(:operator).permit(:name, :website, :checkbox_value, :global)
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.I did

```
<% @batches.each do |batch| %>
  <div class="name_list<%=cycle('odd', 'even')%>"><li>
    <label><%= check_box_tag "send_sms[batch_ids][]",  batch.id,false,:class=>'right' %>
   <div class="att_list_names"> <%= batch.full_name %></div> </label>
   </li>  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it first by adding a teacher role to users and made boolean and set it as `default:false`.

```
rails generate migration add_teacher_to_users teacher:boolean
```

then created a registration as:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label "Tutor/Teacher? Tick" %>
  <%= form.check_box :teacher, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Tick if you are a Tutor" %>
</div>
```