# Rails - Table listing - value as checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In a listing (index.html.erb), how can I display the value of a boolean field as a check_box?

```
<td><%= annotation.active %></td>
```

currently it lists as "true" / "false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **check_box_tag** true
e.g

```
check_box_tag '', '', annotation.active , disabled: true
```

Comment: works - just to find that I made a type ('' instead of ' ')

Answer (score 0):

use [check_box](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) API form `FormHelper`

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'active', annotation.active %></td>
```

And if you want as `checked` use

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'active', annotation.active, true %></td>
```

For more check [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844419/3098330).

Should work !

Comment: @dimitri will you tell us whether your problem has been solve or not?

Comment: it displays as checkbox, yet not with the value from ActiveRecord

Comment: what did you mean? Are you sure that object is present for that record?

Comment: yes am 100% sure I have records - some with value = true, some with value = false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122410/discussion-between-vkatz-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).

Comment: tx! Your solution does display as check-box, yet set to true - irrespective of value of underlying record. Our chat did make my find the typo I made in Stanley Shauro's answer.